# Node.js - NPM packages versioning

Tags: node.js, npm

I recently published a package using NPM. I would like to know how NPM manages versioning.  When does NPM create a new version of a package? Every time I update my NPM `package.json` file?

Also, what strategy should I adopt in terms of keeping my repo in sync with the NPM package versions... In other words, should I be creating tags/branches whenever I update my `package.json` etc.? Any other advice or best practices totally welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version is updated when you update package.json and then publish it using npm. Also, I'd create tags on each version release. This way, people who need to access a specific version can do so in your repo without wading through a mess. Good example: https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/tags